# Android Studio Flamingo | :app:installDebug FAILED - Failure when running trying to run React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, npm-start

Details: It's been about a year since I last ran my React Native app locally. I was able to resolve some outdated npm dependency issues by uninstalling unused and expired packages. In Android Studio, I tried to run the app using the following commands:

1. `npx react-native start`
2. `npx react-native run-android`

What I tried:
After those two commands, I received a lengthy log of failure error messages, starting with:
`Unable to install D:\Workspace\my-app\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl2067087154.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #41) com.my-app.SplashActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installRemotePackage(DeviceImpl.java:1224) at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1050) at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1026) at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1015) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:130)`
Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve these errors?